Early 2000s young adult sci-fi novel about a girl choosing a new robotic body
I'm desperately trying to remember the title of a novel I read in high school (2002-3ish, Western Australia) about a girl who chooses to have a replacement robotic body. The body comes with a management AI companion which she isn't told about (I think it's called Katie?) and at first it's a shock but then she and Katie become friends. There's also a scene where the girl wants to get drunk but Katie shunts the alcohol past her digestive tract so she can't. (weird thing to remember, I know)
I don't remember much else, although the cover was a white background with a female naked-ish body curved in on itself, and I think there was a deep ocean-blue accent around it.

Why did the girl want/need a replacement body? And did other characters have replacement bodies too, or just her?

ummm... I think it was a choice, I think she wanted to get a job or travel somewhere off world? and yes, I think other characters chose to have robotic bodies also

Your description of the cover in particular matches Spare Parts (1999) by Sally Rogers-Davidson.

It was only published in 1999 in Australia, which also fits your criteria very well.
The protagonist is named Kelty.  Her best friend, Mary, is critically injured at an explosion in the recycling plant where they both work.  After the accident, Kelty sells her human body to pay for a transplant for Mary, accepting a cyborg body for herself:

"Very lucky. Unless I'm sadly mistaken, we should be able to arrange a very good deal for you, Miz Holmes. More than enough to pay for a state-of-the-art replacement body."
Napoleone dropped his hands back down to the desk, but Kelty managed to look him in the face as she asked, "And Mary?"
"You could make it a part of the deal that the client donate her used body to Mary, and I'm offering to perform her transplant at a generous discount, which should mean you'll have enough to cover the cost of both transplants."

Kelty doesn't necessarily want to leave Earth, but as a cyborg she is required to go to space.
The built-in computer is named "CATI" which is also very close to what you remember.
There's an extensive excerpt from the book formerly available on the author's website (web archive link).

oh my word you absolute genius!! thank you SO MUCH :D that's it exactly
